# Eclim Could not find or load main class main

Tags: plugin-eclim

I just discovered eclim, I am trying to run Java in my first project with `:Java` but it could not find the main class.

I create the project with `:ProjectCreate test -n java`, open a file test/src/test.java and put the following in it

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, this is a test.");
    }
}
```

save it, and then run `:Java` and get the error `Could not find or load main class main`

The .classpath looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Your java file's name is test.java but class name is Test. Remember, Java is case sensitive. You have to rename the file to Test.java and try again. Main Class name and filename should be of samename. After correcting it, It should work.